# Generating inline font-size style using ReactJS

Tags: css, font-size, inline-styles, reactjs

I am trying to do something like this in ReactJS:

```
var MyReactClass = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var myDivText = "Hello!";
        var myFontSize = 6; //this is actually something more complicated, I'm calculating it on the fly
        var divStyle = {
            font-size: {fontSize + 'px !important;'},
        };
        return (<div style={divStyle}>{myDivText}</div>);
   }
});
```

The problem is that I get this error when I run my code:
"Module build failed: Error: Parse Error: Line 5: Unexpected token -"
apparently, React doesn't like that `font-size` has a dash in it. How do I get around this? Is there some way to escape that character for react? Is there some different css property that react likes better that does the same thing?

Thanks!

Comment: It’s actually JavaScript that throws the error first. An unquoted property name must be a *valid identifier name* or *numeric literal*. Valid code would be: `{'font-size': '10px'}` (with quotes). Allthough I’m not sure how React would handle it.

Comment: It's true that JavaScript has those restrictions on unquoted property names, but this is actually a key in a React style object, not a javascript property, if I understand correctly

Comment: camelCase works inline, and non-camel stylings work in stylesheets. Stylesheets are a common best practice so others don't have to worry about missing anything in a dense code block. Glad you figured it out though!

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use `fontSize` instead of `font-size`

the solution is to camelCase properties which usually contain a dash

http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html

Answered my own question :)

Comment: And if you have something like: -webkit-box-shadow, then just put webkitBoxShadow

Comment: @AndyB You need to actually start that with a capital W so it would be "WebkitBoxShadow". React states vendor prefixes other than ms start with a capital. https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html

Answer (score 1):

I use fontSize: pixels numbers

Answer (score 0):

As https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html says,
We need to remove '-' and upperCase except first word

Example-
`background-color as backgroundColor,`

Same will be applicable everywhere except a few as-

```
aria-* and data-*
```

example-

```
aria-label as aria-label
```

Above worked for me!

Comment: You are confusing HTML attributes like aria-label and data-*, [casing-docs]( https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) and CSS properties created with inline styles like backgroundColor and WebkitTransition https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

Comment: There is nothing to get confuse, instead-of background-color need to use backgroundColor. It is so simple.